# Convert a string to a 'InvariantCulture'

Tags: c#, encoding, utf

I have the following string

```
an-ca
an-ca
```

If you will look it closely you will see that they are different!

To compare 2 string like this I found this solution:

```
if (String.Compare(str1, str2, StringComparison.InvariantCulture) == 0) ...
```

So I have 2 questions

1. Way W3C did characters so are the same in different languages - so make problems of comparision
2. How in C# I can convert the string to 'InvariantCulture'

EDIT:

This [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96529/ch10.htm) may explain the problem better

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ok, I see no difference in those two strings.

Comment: A .NET string doesn't have a culture associated with it - it simply a set of UTF16 characters.

Comment: The site converted it... What exactly I want to do

Comment: [W3C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Wide_Web_Consortium)? What did they do? You're looking for [these guys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode).

Comment: Are you sure it's not just the difference between a dash and an em-dash? Despite looking similar, they are two different characters.

Comment: @Oded there is something in C# so can let me make a string with UTF16 to be more simple? so the 'a' from one cherset will be 'a' in my chareset

Comment: Strings in .NET are encoded as UTF16 already.

Comment: The strings are identical (I did a copy/paste, saved as Unicode, and dumped hex). If there was a difference in your real example, it is gone. Anyway: W3C has nothing to do with the characters. That would be Unicode Consortium. And Unicode only reflected what people used; and also needed to be able to round-trip between existing coded character sets. And characters are not the same in different languages, they might only look the same. For instance, show a "p" to a Russian and he will read it as "r". Same for "c" (the sound it "s" in Russian). Not the same. So you need different codes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of cases for mismatching especially with characters than have no visible differences. For example we assume that a space is always a 32 (0x20) byte. When the text comes from web a space may be a 160 (0xa0) which is the "&nbsp;" entity. And there are more spaces. The same may happen with hyphens, dots, commas etc. Check this [**page**](http://theorem.ca/~mvcorks/code/charsets/auto.html) for more information and especially this [**one**](http://theorem.ca/~mvcorks/cgi-bin/unicode.pl.cgi?start=2000&end=206F) as it contains the most usual cases for this king of mismatches.
With the contained information you can write a function (preferably straight-forward for better performance - aka a long switch) to recreate a string that is already html decoded.

As a proof of concept I'm including the code I'm using for creating a friendly URL and at the same time keep a dictionary for tagging based on titles. It covers only Windows Western and Central European character sets including thorn and eth. As you see there are some tricky parts and of course a lot of space for customization. This spaghetti code makes **only one pass** to the initial string.

```
public static string Latin(this string s, ref Dictionary<string, int> dict)
{
    StringBuilder
        f = new StringBuilder(new string(' ', s.Length * 5)),
        w = new StringBuilder(50);
    string word = "";
    int index = -1, len = s.Length, position = -1, ws = 0;
    while (++index < len)
    {
        if (s[index] > '\x007f')
        {
            switch (s[index])
            {
                case 'á':
                case 'Á':
                case 'à':
                case 'À':
                case 'â':
                case 'Â':
                case 'ä':
                case 'Ä':
                case 'ă':
                case 'Ă':
                case 'ā':
                case 'Ā':
                case 'ã':
                case 'Ã':
                case 'å':
                case 'Å':
                case 'ą':
                case 'Ą':
                    f[++position] = 'a';
                    break;
                case 'æ':
                case 'Æ':
                    f[++position] = 'a';
                    f[++position] = 'e';
                    break;
                case 'ć':
                case 'Ć':
                case 'č':
                case 'Č':
                case 'ç':
                case 'Ç':
                    f[++position] = 'c';
                    break;
                case 'ď':
                case 'Ď':
                case 'đ':
                case 'Đ':
                    f[++position] = 'd';
                    break;
                case 'é':
                case 'É':
                case 'è':
                case 'È':
                case 'ė':
                case 'Ė':
                case 'ê':
                case 'Ê':
                case 'ë':
                case 'Ë':
                case 'ě':
                case 'Ě':
                case 'ē':
                case 'Ē':
                case 'ę':
                case 'Ę':
                    f[++position] = 'e';
                    break;
                case 'ğ':
                case 'Ğ':
                case 'ģ':
                case 'Ģ':
                    f[++position] = 'g';
                    break;
                case 'ı':
                case 'í':
                case 'Í':
                case 'ì':
                case 'Ì':
                case 'İ':
                case 'î':
                case 'Î':
                case 'ï':
                case 'Ï':
                case 'ī':
                case 'Ī':
                case 'į':
                case 'Į':
                    f[++position] = 'i';
                    break;
                case 'ķ':
                case 'Ķ':
                    f[++position] = 'k';
                    break;
                case 'ĺ':
                case 'Ĺ':
                case 'ľ':
                case 'Ľ':
                case 'ļ':
                case 'Ļ':
                case 'ł':
                case 'Ł':
                    f[++position] = 'l';
                    break;
                case 'ń':
                case 'Ń':
                case 'ň':
                case 'Ň':
                case 'ñ':
                case 'Ñ':
                case 'ņ':
                case 'Ņ':
                    f[++position] = 'n';
                    break;
                case 'ó':
                case 'Ó':
                case 'ò':
                case 'Ò':
                case 'ô':
                case 'Ô':
                case 'ö':
                case 'Ö':
                case 'ō':
                case 'Ō':
                case 'õ':
                case 'Õ':
                case 'ő':
                case 'Ő':
                case 'ø':
                case 'Ø':
                    f[++position] = 'o';
                    break;
                case 'œ':
                case 'Œ':
                    f[++position] = 'o';
                    f[++position] = 'e';
                    break;
                case 'ŕ':
                case 'Ŕ':
                case 'ř':
                case 'Ř':
                case 'ŗ':
                case 'Ŗ':
                    f[++position] = 'r';
                    break;
                case 'ś':
                case 'Ś':
                case 'š':
                case 'Š':
                case 'ş':
                case 'Ş':
                    f[++position] = 's';
                    break;
                case 'ß':
                    f[++position] = 's';
                    f[++position] = 's';
                    break;
                case 'ť':
                case 'Ť':
                case 'ţ':
                case 'Ţ':
                    f[++position] = 't';
                    break;
                case 'ð':
                case 'Ð':
                case 'þ':
                case 'Þ':
                    f[++position] = 't';
                    f[++position] = 'h';
                    break;
                case 'ú':
                case 'Ú':
                case 'ù':
                case 'Ù':
                case 'û':
                case 'Û':
                case 'ü':
                case 'Ü':
                case 'ū':
                case 'Ū':
                case 'ů':
                case 'Ů':
                case 'ų':
                case 'Ų':
                case 'ű':
                case 'Ű':
                    f[++position] = 'u';
                    break;
                case 'ý':
                case 'Ý':
                case 'ÿ':
                case 'Ÿ':
                    f[++position] = 'y';
                    break;
                case 'ź':
                case 'Ź':
                case 'ż':
                case 'Ż':
                case 'ž':
                case 'Ž':
                    f[++position] = 'z';
                    break;
                case '\x00a0': // no-break space
                case '\x2000': // other spaces
                case '\x2001':
                case '\x2002':
                case '\x2003':
                case '\x2004':
                case '\x2005':
                case '\x2006':
                case '\x2007':
                case '\x2008':
                case '\x2009':
                case '\x200a':
                case '\x200b':
                case '\x200c':
                case '\x200d':
                    if (position > -1 && f[position] != '-') f[++position] = '-';
                    break;
            }
        }
        else if ((s[index] > '\x002f' && s[index] < '\x003a') || (s[index] > '\x0060' && s[index] < '\x007b'))
        {
            f[++position] = s[index];
        }
        else if ((s[index] > '\x0040' && s[index] < '\x005b'))
        {
            f[++position] = (char)(s[index] | ' ');
        }
        else
        {
            switch (s[index])
            {
                case '#':
                    if (position > 0 && (f[position] == 'c' || f[position] == 'j' || f[position] == 'f'))
                    {
                        f[++position] = 's';
                        f[++position] = 'h';
                        f[++position] = 'a';
                        f[++position] = 'r';
                        f[++position] = 'p';
                    }
                    else if (index + 1 < len && ((s[index + 1] >= '0') && (s[index + 1] <= '9')))
                    {
                        f[++position] = 'n';
                        f[++position] = 'o';
                    }
                    else if (position > -1 && f[position] != '-') f[++position] = '-';
                    break;
                case '+':
                    f[++position] = 'p';
                    f[++position] = 'l';
                    f[++position] = 'u';
                    f[++position] = 's';
                    break;
                case '.':
                    //f[++position] = 'd';
                    //f[++position] = 'o';
                    //f[++position] = 't';
                    break;
                case '-':
                    break;
                default:
                    if (position > -1 && f[position] != '-') f[++position] = '-';
                    break;
            }
        }
        if (f[position] == '-' && ws < position)
        {
            for (var i = ws; i < position; i++) w.Append(f[i]);
            word = w.ToString();
            if (dict.ContainsKey(word)) dict[word] += 1;
            else dict.Add(word, 1);
            w = new StringBuilder(50);
            ws = position + 1;
        }
    }
    if (f[position] == '-') position--;
    return f.ToString(0, position + 1);
}
```

Use it as a guide for you initial requirement.
For the record it generates "c-cplusplus-articles" for "C/C++ articles" and not "c-c---articles" or "cc-articles".

Answer (score 2):

Though it's not foolproof, and still a work in progress, here are some extension methods we've created for converting characters to ASCII from UTF.

```
public static class UnicodeToAsciiConverter
{
    #region Mappings

    /// <summary>
    /// A string-to-string dictionary for mapping unicode text element keys to their
    /// equivalent ASCII text element values. 
    /// </summary>
    private static readonly IDictionary<string, string> UnicodeToAsciiConversions = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "ʼ", SingleQuote }, { "‘", SingleQuote }, { "’", SingleQuote },  { "ʻ", SingleQuote }, { "–", "-" }, 
        { "‎", string.Empty }, { "¯", "_"}, { "—", "-"}, 

        { "á", a }, { "Á", A }, { "à", a }, { "À", A }, { "â", a }, { "Â", A }, { "ä", a }, { "Ä", A }, 
        { "ă", a }, { "Ă", A }, { "ā", a }, { "Ā", A }, { "ã", a }, { "Ã", A }, { "å", a }, { "Å", A }, 
        { "ầ", a }, { "Ầ", A }, { "ắ", a }, { "Ắ", A }, { "ằ", a }, { "Ằ", A }, { "ẵ", a }, { "Ẵ", A }, 
        { "ả", a }, { "Ả", A }, { "ạ", a }, { "Ạ", A }, { "ậ", a }, { "Ậ", A }, { "ấ", a }, { "Ấ", A }, 
        { "ą", a }, { "Ą", A }, 

        { "æ", "ae" }, { "Æ", "AE" }, { "ǣ", "ae" }, { "Ǣ", "AE" }, 
        { "ß", b }, { "þ", b }, { "Þ", B }, 

        { "ć", c }, { "Ć", C }, { "č", c }, { "Č", C }, { "ç", c }, { "Ç", C }, { "ĉ", c }, { "Ĉ", C }, 
        { "ċ", c }, { "Ċ", C }, 
        { "ḑ", d }, { "Ḑ", D }, { "đ", d }, { "Đ", D }, { "ð", d }, { "Ð", D }, { "ḍ", d }, { "Ḍ", D }, 
        { "ď", d }, { "Ď", D }, { "ḑ", d }, { "Ḑ", D }, 

        { "é", e }, { "É", E }, { "è", e }, { "È", E }, { "ė", e }, { "Ė", E }, { "ê", e }, { "Ê", E }, 
        { "ë", e }, { "Ë", E }, { "ě", e }, { "Ě", E }, { "ĕ", e }, { "Ĕ", E }, { "ē", e }, { "Ē", E }, 
        { "ę", e }, { "Ę", E }, { "ế", e }, { "Ế", E }, { "ề", e }, { "Ề", E }, { "ệ", e }, { "Ệ", E }, 
        { "ǝ", e }, { "Ǝ", E }, { "ə", e }, { "Ə", E }, { "ể", e }, { "Ể", E }, { "ễ", e }, { "Ễ", E }, 
        { "ẹ̀", e }, { "Ẹ̀", E }, { "ɛ́", e }, { "ɛ", e }, { "Ɛ", E }, 

        { "ğ", g }, { "Ğ", G }, { "ĝ", g }, { "Ĝ", G }, { "ġ", g }, { "Ġ", G }, { "ģ", g }, { "Ģ", G }, 
        { "ḩ", h }, { "Ḩ", H }, { "ħ", h }, { "Ħ", H }, { "ḥ", h }, { "Ḥ", H }, { "ĥ", h }, { "Ĥ", H }, 
        { "ẖ", h }, { "H̱", H }, { "h̲", h }, { "H̲", H }, { "ḩ", h }, { "Ḩ", H }, 

        { "ı", i }, { "ı".ToUpper(), I }, { "í", i }, { "Í", I }, { "ì", i }, { "Ì", I }, { "İ".ToLower(), i }, { "İ", I }, 
        { "î", i }, { "Î", I }, { "ï", i }, { "Ï", I }, { "ĭ", i }, { "Ĭ", I }, { "ī", i }, { "Ī", I }, 
        { "ĩ", i }, { "Ĩ", I }, { "ỉ", i }, { "Ỉ", I }, { "ị", i }, { "Ị", I }, 
        { "ķ", k }, { "Ķ", K }, 
        { "ļ", l }, { "Ļ", L }, { "ł", l }, { "Ł", L }, { "ľ", l }, { "Ľ", L }, 
        { "ň", n }, { "Ň", N }, { "ñ", n }, { "Ñ", N }, { "ń", n }, { "Ń", N }, { "ŋ", n }, { "Ŋ", N }, 
        { "ņ", n }, { "Ņ", N }, 

        { "ó", o }, { "Ó", O }, { "ò", o }, { "Ò", O }, { "ô", o }, { "Ô", O }, { "ö", o }, { "Ö", O }, 
        { "ŏ", o }, { "Ŏ", O }, { "ō", o }, { "Ō", O }, { "õ", o }, { "Õ", O }, { "ő", o }, { "Ő", O }, 
        { "ố", o }, { "Ố", O }, { "ồ", o }, { "Ồ", O }, { "ø", o }, { "Ø", O }, { "ơ", o }, { "Ơ", O }, 
        { "ọ", o }, { "Ọ", O }, { "ớ", o }, { "Ớ", O }, { "ộ", o }, { "Ộ", O }, { "ɔ", o }, { "Ɔ", O }, 
        { "ɔ́", o }, { "Ɔ́", O }, { "ổ", o }, { "Ổ", O }, { "ỏ", o }, { "Ỏ", O }, 

        { "œ", oe }, { "Œ", OE }, { "œ̆", oe }, { "Œ̆", OE }, 

        { "ř", r }, { "Ř", R }, 
        { "ś", s }, { "Ś", S }, { "š", s }, { "Š", S }, { "ş", s }, { "Ş", S }, { "ṣ", s }, { "Ṣ", S }, 
        { "ŝ", s }, { "Ŝ", S }, { "ș", s }, { "s̲", s }, { "S̲", S }, 
        { "ţ", t }, { "Ţ", T }, { "ṭ", t }, { "Ṭ", T }, { "ŧ", t }, { "Ŧ", T }, { "ț", t }, { "ť", t }, { "Ť", T }, 

        { "ú", u }, { "Ú", U }, { "ù", u }, { "Ù", U }, { "ü", u }, { "Ü", U }, { "ŭ", u }, { "Ŭ", U }, 
        { "ū", u }, { "Ū", U }, { "ũ", u }, { "Ũ", U }, { "ų", u }, { "Ų", U }, { "ủ", u }, { "Ủ", U }, 
        { "ư", u }, { "Ư", U }, { "ừ", u }, { "Ừ", U }, { "û", u }, { "Û", U }, { "ự", u }, { "Ự", U }, 
        { "ů", u }, { "Ů", U }, { "ụ", u }, { "Ụ", U }, { "ṳ", u }, { "Ṳ", U }, { "ứ", u }, { "Ứ", U }, 
        { "ŵ", w }, { "Ŵ", W }, 
        { "ý", y }, { "Ý", Y }, { "ỹ", y }, { "Ỹ", Y }, { "ỳ", y }, { "Ỳ", Y }, 
        { "ź", z }, { "Ź", Z }, { "ž", z }, { "Ž", Z }, { "z̄", z }, { "Z̄", Z }, { "z̧", z }, { "Z̧", Z }, 
        { "ż", z }, { "Ż", Z }, { "ẕ", z }, { "Ẕ", Z }, 

    };

    #region ASCII Constants

    // ReSharper disable InconsistentNaming
    // ascii constants save memory for immutable strings
    private const string SingleQuote = "'";
    private const string a = "a";
    private const string A = "A";
    private const string b = "b";
    private const string B = "B";
    private const string c = "c";
    private const string C = "C";
    private const string d = "d";
    private const string D = "D";
    private const string e = "e";
    private const string E = "E";
    private const string g = "g";
    private const string G = "G";
    private const string h = "h";
    private const string H = "H";
    private const string i = "i";
    private const string I = "I";
    private const string k = "k";
    private const string K = "K";
    private const string l = "l";
    private const string L = "L";
    private const string n = "n";
    private const string N = "N";
    private const string o = "o";
    private const string O = "O";
    private const string oe = "oe";
    private const string OE = "OE";
    private const string r = "r";
    private const string R = "R";
    private const string s = "s";
    private const string S = "S";
    private const string t = "t";
    private const string T = "T";
    private const string u = "u";
    private const string U = "U";
    private const string w = "w";
    private const string W = "W";
    private const string y = "y";
    private const string Y = "Y";
    private const string z = "z";
    private const string Z = "Z";
    // ReSharper restore InconsistentNaming

    #endregion
    #endregion
    #region Conversion

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts unicode text to its ASCII equivalent using a 2-pass algorithm. 
    /// <para>
    /// In the first pass, the <paramref name="unicodeText"/> parameter is searched 
    /// for text present in the <see cref="UnicodeToAsciiConversions"/> dictionary. 
    /// For each match, the unicode text is replaced with its equivalent ASCII text 
    /// from the dictionary. <em>It cannot be guaranteed that each non-ASCII character
    /// will be converted after the first pass.</em>
    /// </para>
    /// <para>
    /// The second pass guarantees that the converted text will be ASCII-compatible. 
    /// This is achieved by replacing all incompatible charaters with a question mark 
    /// (?) character.
    /// </para>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="unicodeText">
    /// The unicode text to convert to an ASCII equivalent.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>
    /// The ASCII equivalent of the <paramref name="unicodeText"/> value.
    /// </returns>
    private static string Convert(string unicodeText)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(unicodeText))
            return unicodeText;

        var asciiBuilder = new StringBuilder(unicodeText);
        foreach (var conversion in UnicodeToAsciiConversions)
        {
            if (unicodeText.Contains(conversion.Key))
            {
                asciiBuilder.Replace(conversion.Key, conversion.Value);
            }
        }
        asciiBuilder.Replace("·", string.Empty);
        asciiBuilder.Replace("‎", string.Empty);
        var utf8Encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
        var asciiEncoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        var convertedToAsciiPass1 = asciiBuilder.ToString();
        var utfBytes = utf8Encoding.GetBytes(convertedToAsciiPass1);
        if (utfBytes.Contains((byte)204) && utfBytes.Contains((byte)129))
        {
            var utfList = utfBytes.ToList();
            while (utfList[utfList.IndexOf(204) + 1] == 129)
            {
                utfList.RemoveAt(utfList.IndexOf(204) + 1);
                utfList.RemoveAt(utfList.IndexOf(204));
            }
            utfBytes = utfList.ToArray();
        }
        var asciiBytes = Encoding.Convert(utf8Encoding, asciiEncoding, utfBytes);
        var convertedToAsciiPass2 = asciiEncoding.GetString(asciiBytes);
        return convertedToAsciiPass2;
    }

    #endregion
    #region String Extension Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts unicode text to its ASCII equivalent using the 
    /// <see cref="UnicodeToAsciiConverter.Convert(System.String)"/> implementation.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// This is simply a shortcut to provide a more fluent API when converting 
    /// unicode text values to their ASCII equivalents. 
    /// </remarks>
    /// <returns>
    /// The ASCII equivalent of the this text value.
    /// </returns>
    public static string ConvertToAscii(this string unicodeText)
    {
        return Convert(unicodeText);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether a string of text contains only question marks and 
    /// whitespace characters. This is useful in determining whether a conversion
    /// from unicode to ASCII failed completely, as often happens with languages
    /// like Arabic. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// <code>True</code> if this string of text contains only question marks and whitespace
    /// characters, otherwise <code>false</code>.
    /// </returns>
    public static bool ContainsOnlyQuestionMarksAndWhiteSpace(this string text)
    {
        return text.All(character => character == '?' || character == ' ' || character == '\'' 
            || character == '-' || character == '_' || character == '(' || character == ')'
            || character == ',' || character == '/' || character == '.' || character == '&'
            || character == '"');
    }

    #endregion

}
```

Comment: Thanks - not exactly what I need but this will help

Comment: You're wrong about the constants.  All C# string literals are interned, so `"A"` and `"A"` refer to the same instance.

Comment: @SLaks, thanks for looking at this and pointing out where it needs improvement. Exactly which part of the code are you talking about?

Comment: Nevermind, I think I see now. I should get rid of the private const string Letter = "Letter" lines. Thanks for this, will update.

Comment: Could've been a copy-paste problem, but I've found duplicates { "Ð", D }, { "ḍ", d }, { "Ḍ", D }, { "ḩ", h }, { "Ḩ", H } , a missing { "ŗ", r }, { "Ŗ", R } and a questionable case { "ß", "ss" }.