# C# Dictionary key lookup in an InvariantCulture way

Tags: c#, dictionary, string-comparison, invariantculture

My application handles some texts parsing and uses a proper noun cache to reduce database calls:

```
Dictionary<String, ProperNoun> ProperNounsDict;

if (!ProperNounsDict.ContainsKey(word))
{
    var newProper = new ProperNoun() { Word = word  };
    ProperNounsDict.Add(word, newProper);

    UnitOfWork.ProperNounRepository.Insert(newProper);
    try
    {
        UnitOfWork.SaveChangesEx();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         // 
    }
}
```

The problem is that database and C# treat equality of strings in a different way, so I can run into duplicate key error (SQL) for similar words:

**1) Database** (SQL Server 2014)

```
Column_name  Type       Collation
Word         nvarchar   Latin1_General_100_CS_AS
```

`Saevarsson` and `Sævarsson` are the same thing from the database perspective and it is fine for me, since words containing characters æ are very rare in parsed texts:

```
select * from dict.ProperNoun where Word = N'Saevarsson'  -- returns both Saevarsson and Sævarsson
```

**2) C#**

```
string s1 = "Sævarsson";
string s2 = "Saevarsson";
bool equals = s1.Equals(s2, StringComparison.InvariantCulture);
```

s1 and s2 are seen as equal, if comparison is done in an InvariantCulture way

**Question: is there a way to check for a string key existence in an InvariantCulture way?** I do not want to loose my O(1) complexity of checking for key existence, if possible.

Things I have tried:

**a) Database check** - for cache misses, before inserting into the cache, also check in DB. Generates a lot of queries, so performance is awful

**b) String normalization** - replace undesired characters with "normal" ones using a map similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8464394/2780791). Requires a lot of work and I feel it can be automated since `StringComparison.InvariantCulture` knows how to deal with this.

Thanks.

Comment: You can create new dictionary and pass `StringComparer.InvariantCulture` to constructor... It will be O(1)

Answer (score 5):

When you initialize your dictionary, you can use constructor with [`IEqualityComparer<TKey>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132073(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Dictionary<String, ProperNoun> ProperNounsDict = 
    new Dictionary<String, ProperNoun>(StringComparer.InvariantCulture);
```

In this case your keys will be compared using invariant culture. You can use other [string comparers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer(v=vs.110).aspx0) as well, depending on your needs.

Comment: Yes. It is exactly what I need. In my case the initialization is done from database: `UnitOfWork.ProperNounRepository.AllNoTracking.ToDictionary(pn => pn.Word, pn => pn, StringComparer.InvariantCulture));`. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Use this constructor for creating the dictionary.

```
Dictionary<String, ProperNoun> ProperNounsDict = new Dictionary<String, ProperNoun>(StringComparer.InvariantCulture);
```